# jQuery dynamic table row generation on selection of drop down list value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp

how to popup a dynamic table and generate dynamic table row on selection of a value from a drop down list using jQuery in jsp in struts 2

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, go to the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (You'll get a badge as well) and spend few minutes in [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you need not `JSP` and `Struts2` for your purpose. Please find the snippet below,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter = 0;
    $("#ddlist").change(function() {
        $("#preq tbody").append('<tr id="row' + counter + '"><td>'
        +$(this).val()
        +'</td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
        counter++;
    });
});
```

See the working [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/vinzykrish/jq9ng/77/). Hope this helps.